# how can I change objects in array to string to type?

Tags: typescript

How can I take an array object like

```
const array = [{word:"apple"}, {word:"banana"}, {word:"melon"}]
```

and extract from it a type like

```
type Test = "apple" | "banana" | "melon"
```

?

Comment: In addition to [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) inference, you can use [const parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) inference if the site is a function: [example](https://tsplay.dev/Nda6Xm)

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell the compiler that it should remember the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `word` property of the array elements, otherwise it will infer `array` as type `{word: string}[]`, and the information you need to build `Test` will be lost forever.  The easiest way to do this is with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const array = [{ word: "apple" }, { word: "banana" }, { word: "melon" }] as const;

/* const array: readonly [
  { readonly word: "apple"; }, 
  { readonly word: "banana"; }, 
  { readonly word: "melon"; }
] */
```

Now `array`'s type is a very specific [`readonly` tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) whose elements have [`readonly` properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties) of string literal types.

---

From there it's straightforward to [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into the type of `array` (via the [`typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html)):

```
type Test = (typeof array)[number]["word"];
// type Test = "apple" | "banana" | "melon"
```

That is, `typeof array` is the type of `array`, and when you index into `array` with a `number` you'll get the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the types of its elements, each of which has a `word` property, so you index into *that* with a key of type `"word"` you get the union of those types, which is equivalent to `"apple" | "banana" | "melon"` as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gbxgdxAQBMAuGAIjgAdqAbAUwpgF8AaGPQk8igIzhhBcZu04EiZSgFsGdcKIC68CDFCQoAbgBQAegBUa8NHhJU5BAzjFwdNFm0xxl67bTcpVWowqbWHR2crGzA7CR5KASEhX38YQLwXELCPXll5MFiWbWV9XW0oFGoGGAAVBhNMQuKQADNTZBQsMABXaT4GBEUsCg8KRR1dXRhqkvLKyhp6JhgAH0jhGLmZOQUgA)